# Permission denied to call method HTMLAnchorElement.focus

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox4, permission-denied

After upgrading to Firefox 4, I started seeing this error on a site I maintain:

```
Permission denied for <...> to call method HTMLAnchorElement.focus
```

I have built a simple scenario to recreate the error:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a id="lnk" href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
        <form>
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
        <script>
            document.onkeypress = function(e) {
                e = (e ? e : event);
                var key = (e.which ? e.which : e.keyCode);
                if(key == 13) {
                    var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
                    lnk.focus();
                    return false;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

This worked fine before upgrading to Firefox 4... however, I do not believe the issue is exactly Firefox's fault, either.  I say this because it actually only appears to happen on my desktop installation.  I can use the same page on other FF4 installs with no error.  I have disabled all of my extensions and restarted, but the error persists.  Any idea what change/addon/plugin/whatever I might have on my installation that would be causing this?

Thanks...

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by setting the focus to the link when the user presses enter?

Comment: I tried your page in firfox 4 with no problem. pressing enter on the page focuses the link. I am not using any addons, I'd try disabling yours and reenabling them one at a time

Comment: @daniellmb : The original code from my site actually focuses the link, then "clicks" it.  The focus is there because on some of our pages, textboxes have onblur events that need to fire and simply clicking the link didn't allow for that.

Comment: @kennebec : As stated, I disabled all of my extensions and the problem persists, otherwise I would follow your approach.  So I don't really think it is an extension (unless it can change FF behavior even when disabled). Any other ideas? Thanks...

Comment: All this code is running on the same domain right? This isn't a cross origin security issue is it?

Comment: @daniellmb Yes, I forgot to mention that--no cross domain activity going on here (and no frames even, for that matter). The HTML/JS I posted above is all that is needed to generate the error on my install (upon pressing enter).

Answer (score 0):

Since it only happens on that one machine its probably an environment issue with your set up, hard to say, I'm not able to reproduce it either. I have seen some examples that suggest adding a setTimeout delay, shot in the dark but you could try it.

Comment: Thanks for the response, daniellmb. I agree with you that it is an environment issue--and quite probably Stack Overflow isn't the place for this question, but I wasn't sure if any stack site would be quite right either... so I thought I'd post to see if anyone else had seen it, or if I was doing something wrong in the code.